# Bootstrap show search bar underneath navigation

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show navigation underneath the navigation when the menu is in collapsed state. But when I implement collapse at 1200 width the search bar gets display to the right even when the menu has collapsed.

Secondly since I am using a div to seperate both the sections of navigation, when I use mega menu style the width of the dropdown is limited to col-md-9. I would rather want it to be till the end which is the full width of the navigation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
    height: 80px!important;
}
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
}


.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
       position: static;
       float: none;
       width: auto;
       margin-top: 0;
       background-color: transparent;
       border: 0;
       -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
            line-height: 20px!important;
        padding-top: 10px!important;
            padding-bottom: 10px!important;
    }
    .navbar-brand>img { 
      position:absolute!important;
      left: -50px!important;
      top: 0px!important;
      padding: 0px!important;
    }
```

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/93ya7Lsc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use container-fluid instead of row

at larger resolution >1200 the nav and search bar will be on the same row
so use

`col-lg-9` on navbar-header and `col-lg-3` on navbar-form

[image]

on resolution less than <1200 they will be in different rows.

**Update: also use the following css**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .input-group-btn{
    width: 1% !important;
    }
    }
```

[heres the updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6bv6cjr/1/)

Comment: The issue with the solution is that when the search bar isn't of full width for larger width with collapse menu and secondly when the collapse menu isn't there the search menu is not aligned

Comment: updated the answer. bootstrap adds width:auto on .input-group-btn class on screen less than 768px.